# How to close popover menu if its child i.e.menu-item is clicked in Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a popover menu and a menu-item component which is I am using together to display a popover list menu list.

Code example:

```
<div class="main">
    <popover-menu>
        <menu-item> Menu 1 </menu-item>  
        <menu-item> Menu 2 </menu-item>  
        <menu-item> Menu 3 </menu-item>                           
    </popover-menu>
</main
```

So basically I am stuck here:

1. How to close/hide popover-menu if click on menu-item.
2. How to use boolean value outside of popover-menu to know when is pop-over menu open/close.

For example:

```
<div class="main" [class.menu-open]="isMenuOpen"></div>
```

Any help would be really appreciated, thanks.

**Edit**

I want to use popover-menu and menu-item selector on HTML page

PopoverMenuComponent

```
@Component({
  selector: 'popover-menu',
  template: `
  <div>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  <div>
  `
})
```

MenuItemComponent

```
@Component({
      selector: 'menu-item',
      template: `
      <div>
        <ng-content></ng-content>
      <div>
      `
    })
```

HTML

```
<div class="main">
    <popover-menu>
        <menu-item> Menu 1 </menu-item>  
        <menu-item> Menu 2 </menu-item>  
        <menu-item> Menu 3 </menu-item>                           
    </popover-menu>
</main
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**menu.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'menu',
  template: `
  <div *ngIf="opened">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </div>
  `
})
export class MenuComponent  {
  @Output() openedChange = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  private _opened: boolean;
   @Input() set opened(v: boolean) {
     this._opened = v;
     this.openedChange.next(v)
   }

   get opened() {
     return this._opened;
   }

   toggle() {
     this.opened = !this.opened;
   }

}
```

**menu-item.component.ts**

```
import { Component, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { MenuComponent } from './menu.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'menu-item',
  template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`
})
export class MenuItemComponent {

  @HostListener('click') onClick() {
    this.menu.toggle();
  }

  constructor(private menu: MenuComponent) { }
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <div> Opened in the component class: {{ opened }} </div>
  <div> Menu component internal state: {{ menu.opened }} </div>

  <button (click)="toggle()">Toggle</button>

  <menu #menu [(opened)]="opened">
    <menu-item>One</menu-item>
    <menu-item>Two</menu-item>
    <menu-item>Three</menu-item>
  </menu>
  `
})
export class AppComponent  {
  opened = true;

  toggle() {
    this.opened = !this.opened;
  }
}
```

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jafsaj)

With this implementation clicking on any `menu-item` will toggle the `menu` component. It is achieved by injecting the reference to the `MenuComponent` in `MenuItemComponent`'s constructor. Now the child `MenuItemComponent` can trigger the `toggle()` method of the parent `MenuComponent`.

The `<menu>` also component exposes the `[opened]` `@Input` and `(openedChange)` `@Output` which allows for two way binding of the menu state by components that want to use the menu.

Comment: I want to use 'menu-item' inside 'menu' selector on html page not in menuComponent.

Comment: Can we write toggle logic in menu component and close/hide menu if click menu-item?

Comment: Yes you can. I'll edit my response in a few minutes.

Comment: @S.Choubey check out the new implementation

Comment: Thank you so much. Do we still need to write toggle logic on the page (AppComponent)? Can we shift toggle method in menuComponent? Actually there are several pages where I need to reuse this component.

Comment: The app.component logic is only there to allow you to change the menu state based on the app.component's  `opened` value. If you only care about the menu-item clicks, just remove the app.component logic, along with the `[(opened)]` binding.

Answer (score 0):

Using [EventEmitters](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter)

In `MenuItemComponent`, add

```
@Output() clicked: EventEmitter<bool> = new EventEmitter();

itemClicked() {
     this.clicked.emit(true);
}
```

Also, in the template for it, add an event listener for when the item is clicked. like

```
<li (click)="itemClicked()"> menu Item 1</li>
```

And in the html,

```
<div class="main" [class.menu-open]="isMenuOpen">
    <popover-menu>
        <menu-item (clicked)="isMenuOpen = true"> Menu 1 </menu-item>  
        <menu-item (clicked)="isMenuOpen = true"> Menu 2 </menu-item>  
        <menu-item (clicked)="isMenuOpen = true"> Menu 3 </menu-item>                           
    </popover-menu>
</div>
```

The approach I'm using is here(https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event).
The documentation also lists other ways you can do this.